# Shift browser contents to the left while viewing in wide screen

Tags: firefox, ubuntu, console

I use a widescreen laptop. Many websites have their content centre aligned. On wider screens this means lot of empty space on left and right. As such this is not a botheration.

Many a times, I read some instructions on the web page and type them out on the command prompt. I prefer to overlay the command prompt window on top of the browser and if the browser contents are left aligned (or right aligned), then I need not Alt-tab across these windows.

I use Firefox on Ubuntu. I use the command line (konsole) heavily. I know compiz (and similar) tools provides transparent windows so that the content beneath is visible. But I don't want to install compiz or its equivalent because my graphics driver is not all that good.

Any addon or simple trick that would shift the page content to the left (or right) would be very helpful (read productive).

Answer (score 1):

The path of least resistance is: Don't maximise the window - leave it as a floating window and move it over so it is side-by-side with your command prompt.

If you really want to be funky, override the stylesheet using a user defined stylesheet that has a fixed margin on either the left or right, so the space is never used by the web page.

Comment: floating window is what i do now (though a bit inconvenient)